# listfragment on click into custom list in another fragment

Tags: android, android-listfragment

when i click on listfragment particular data that data has to be shown in custom listview in second fragment.means that clicked item has to be add in the second fragment.
    but list view is not appearing..

```
public class MyPlayerFrag extends Fragment  {

    Context context;    
    CustomDetailAdapter adapter;

    ListView list;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    ArrayList<String> title =new ArrayList<String>();   
    ArrayList<String> description =new ArrayList<String>(); 

    @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onAttach(activity);

    }


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail, container,false);
            list = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listview);    

            return v;

    }

    public void detailData(Context applicationContext,ArrayList<String> data1,ArrayList<String> data2){

                this.title =data1;
        this.description=data2;

            CustomDetailAdapter adapter =new CustomDetailAdapter(context, title, description);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);


here am getting output like in log System.out.println(" title::"+ title);
as[keyboard1,keyboard2]


    }


    }

    public class CustomDetailAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        Context context ;
        ArrayList<String> items= null;
        ArrayList<String> items1= null;     

        public CustomDetailAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> items, ArrayList<String> items1) {

            this.context =context;
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub         
            this.items = items;
        this.items1 = items1;




        }

        /*private view holder class*/
     private class ViewHolder {      
            TextView txtTitle;
            TextView txtDesc;

        }




     public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



         ViewHolder holder = null;  

         System.out.println("am in getview");        

          mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            if (convertView == null) {

                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.player, null); 
                    holder = new ViewHolder();

                    holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);                  
                   holder.txtDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);                     

            } else {
                 holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }


                holder.txtTitle.setText(items1.get(position));          
               holder.txtDesc.setText(items.get(position));

        return convertView;

        }



        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return items;
        }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }



    }
```

Comment: You should debug your code and see if the values are being set in second fragment, also to pass data between fragments use a bundle with setArguments and getArguments, don't use setters.

Comment: Where did you passed FragmentInterface object to listfragment ??

Comment: You should use your Activity is a middle-man to communicate between both fragments which belongs to same activity

Comment: @pankaj-i edited the fragment interface object code above.how to solve this issue.